# RecyclerView with one static card and other dynamic cards

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to do this: a RecycleView with CardView. The first card is static: it show "Details for this order". The other cards after the first are dynamics. So I decided to do this code:

```
public class DocumentTypeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
{



private List<DocumentType> document; //lista di card da riempire
private Context context;


public DocumentTypeAdapter(List<DocumentType>document, Context context)
{
    this.document = document;
    this.context = context;
}


public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{

    View view;

    if(viewType == 0)
    {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_info, parent, false);
        ViewSimple simpleView = new ViewSimple(view);
        return simpleView;
    }
    else
    {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_info, parent, false);
        DocumentTypeViewHolder documentTypeViewHolder = new DocumentTypeViewHolder(view);
        return documentTypeViewHolder;
    }

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{

    DocumentType documents = document.get(position);

    if(getItemViewType(position)!=0) 
    {
        holder.title.setText(documents.getTitle());
        holder.cert.setText(documents.getTypeofCertificate());
        holder.lastmod.setText(documents.getLastModified());
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return document.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
    return document.size();
}

private class ViewSimple extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public ViewSimple(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
    }
}


public class DocumentTypeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{
    TextView title, lastmod,cert;

    public DocumentTypeViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tipo);
        lastmod = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ultimamodifica);
        cert = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.certificato);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {


    }
}
}
```

but it doesn't work.
My question are:

1. how to make the first card static and other dynamics?
2. my data are in `document` list. So how to say to method  `getItemViewType()` that the first card is static and others are generated from the size of the list `document`?

Edit: this is the code with changes:

```
public class DocumentTypeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
{


private static final int STATIC_CARD = 0;
private static final int DYNAMIC_CARD = 1;
private List<DocumentType> document; 
private Context context;


public DocumentTypeAdapter(List<DocumentType>document, Context context)
{
    this.document = document;
    this.context = context;
}


public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View view;

    if(viewType == STATIC_CARD)
    {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_info, parent, false);
        ViewSimple simpleView = new ViewSimple(view);
        return simpleView;
    }
    else
    {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.document_card_type, parent, false);
        DocumentTypeViewHolder documentTypeViewHolder = new DocumentTypeViewHolder(view);
        return documentTypeViewHolder;
    }

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{

    DocumentType documents = document.get(position);

    if(getItemViewType(position)==DYNAMIC_CARD)
    {
        DocumentTypeViewHolder mHolder = (DocumentTypeViewHolder)holder;
        mHolder.data.setText(documents.getData());
        mHolder.status.setText(documents.getStatus());

        Picasso.with(context).load(documents.getImage().toString()).into(mHolder.image, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

                Log.d("Picasso","success");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError()
            {

                Log.d("Picasso","error");

            }
        });

    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return document.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
   if(position == 0)
    return STATIC_CARD;

   else
    return DYNAMIC_CARD;


}

private class ViewSimple extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public ViewSimple(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
    }
}


public class DocumentTypeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView data, status;
    ImageView image;

    public DocumentTypeViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);

         data = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateCharging);
         status =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.statusCharging);
         image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.documentImage);

    }


}
}
```

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should override `getItemViewType()` and make it return a different value when it should be a dynamic card or when its a static card. Since you want the first card to be static you should return a different value when position == 0. This will look something like this:

```
    private static final int STATIC_CARD = 0;
    private static final int DYNAMIC_CARD = 1;

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(position == 0) {
            return STATIC_CARD;
        } else {
            return DYNAMIC_CARD;
        }
    }
```

Then in your `onCreateViewHolder()` method you should check the `viewType` and based on the outcome you should inflate a `View`, which you were already doing OK, but I would replace the hardcoded 0 with the `private static final int STATIC_CARD`.

**Edit:** Just came to my mind, if you only need one static card, you might want to consider placing a `CardView` in your `Fragment`/`Activity` xml layout and place the rest of the dynamic cards in a `RecyclerView` below that static card.

Comment: so getItemViewType( ) returns only 0 - 1 in this case?

Comment: yea, for example: 0 for static card and 1 for dynamic card

Comment: and in onBindViewHolder I have to do the same?

Comment: yes, just call getItemViewType(position) and check whether it returns 0 or 1

Comment: I've read your Edit, so the solution with "STATIC" and "DYNAMIC" works in the same mode of the create static card in the layout?

Comment: No, my edit suggests you could also fairly easily add a CardView element to your Fragment or Activity's xml layout, and below that hardcoded CardView you can place your RecyclerView with the rest of your dynamic items, so your RecyclerView will only be filled with the dynamic cards, therefore there will be no more need to use the viewTypes in your adapter, but I would still prefer the solution with the viewTypes, because of the better extendability

Comment: I try to do it, it shows me only the STATIC cards.. I also do something in the main fragment?

Comment: yea, in the xml layout of your fragment, place the static card at the top and place the RecyclerView with the rest of the dynamic cards below that.

Comment: I made an edit of my question, with code that shows me only static cards

Comment: Change these:
DocumentType documents = document.get(position - 1);
return document.size() + 1;

Comment: it gives me this error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1

Comment: place DocumentType documents = document.get(position); inside the if statement

Comment: I found the error: if I put three card dinamically, it shows only two cards!

Comment: Hi, If I want to have last card as static card how to do, plz suggest a solution

Answer (score 2):

I'll suggest you to use a library that already correctly implement/handles all that for you: https://github.com/eyeem/RecyclerViewTools

**Full disclosure:** I wrote the library

Just write your adapter for the dynamic items and then:

```
DocumentTypeAdapter adapter = new // your adapter here
WrapAdapter wrapAdapter = new WrapAdapter(adapter); // that's from the library
wrapAdapter.addHeader( /* add here your static view */ );
recyclerView.setAdapter(wrapAdapter);
```

and add those to your build.gradle

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.eyeem.recyclerviewtools:library:0.0.3-SNAPSHOT@aar'
}
```