# Setting RecyclerView Header without overriding first element

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Hello i have a recyclerView which displays cards containing data fetched from mysql with retrofit. In my adapter, I was able to set the first card to a static element which is the user's profile picture as suggested by the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385756/recyclerview-with-one-static-card-and-other-dynamic-cards).  However they didn't notice that the method overrides the former first element (element at position 0). The first element gets replaced by the static view but i don't want that. I want

```
static card,
cardview 0,
cardview 1,
cardview 2,
etc
```

Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an easy way like listview.addHeaderView() but you can achieve this by adding a type to your adapter for header.

Here is an example

```
public class HeaderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
    String[] data;

    public HeaderAdapter(String[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder
            return new VHItem(null);
        } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
            //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder
            return new VHHeader(null);
        }

        throw new RuntimeException("there is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " + make sure your using types correctly");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof VHItem) {
            String dataItem = getItem(position);
            //cast holder to VHItem and set data
        } else if (holder instanceof VHHeader) {
            //cast holder to VHHeader and set data for header.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.length + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isPositionHeader(position))
            return TYPE_HEADER;

        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
        return position == 0;
    }

    private String getItem(int position) {
        return data[position - 1];
    }

    class VHItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title;

        public VHItem(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    class VHHeader extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        Button button;

        public VHHeader(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I keep getting unknown class TYPE_ITEM and unknown class TYPE_HEADER.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'viewType' in 'RecyclerView.Adapter'.

onCreateViewHolder in RecyclerView

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    int layout = -1;
    switch (viewType) {
        case RecyclerViewItem.USER_PROFILE:
            layout = R.layout.driving_item;
            break;
        case RecyclerViewItem.OTHER_USER_PROFILE:
            layout = R.layout.date_item;
            break;
        case RecyclerViewItem.DATE:
            layout = R.layout.send_button_item;
            break;
    }

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layout, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(v);
}
```

onBindViewHolder in RecyclerView

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int position) {
    final int pos = myViewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
    if (pos == -1) {
        return;
    }
    final RecyclerViewItem item = ArrayList.get(pos);

    switch (item.getType()) {
        case RecyclerViewItem.USER_PROFILE:
            //By type you want to do differently.
            break;
        case RecyclerViewItem.OTHER_USER_PROFILE:
            //By type you want to do differently.
            break;
        case RecyclerViewItem.DATE:
            //By type you want to do differently.
            break;
    }
}
```

f you have any additional questions, please let me know by comment.

Comment: this doesn't work. The first item is still replaced.